# Read cells in csv file

Tags: bash

I have this table of numbers saved in `csv` file format as follow:

```
5,  6,  9,  5,
2,  8,  1,  1, 
1,  2,  3,  6,
. . .  . .
. . .  . .
. . .  . .
. . .  . .
```

Every row in this table describe a rectangle dimensions.

I wanted to feed the four numbers of every row in a command line to create the rectangle as follow:

```
rectang -cs x1 x2  x3 x4  # rectang is a script to create rectangle; -cs flag means dimensions; x1, x2, x3 x4 the rectangle dimensions
```

I am thinking to convert the csv file "`table.csv`" to tab deliminated text "`table.txt`"  file then using it in a for loop as follow:

```
for i in $(cat table.txt); do
rectang -cs x1 x2  x3 x4
done
```

but I don't know how to feed x1 x2 x3 x4 from the table to the command "rectang"

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are the existing lines space-separated (not Comma-Separated) Values?

Comment: @JeffSchaller. Actually "Comma-Separated"

Comment: The table in your question is misleading, then. The answers to this point are assuming spaces instead of commas.

Comment: @JeffSchaller. I fixed it in the question. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` command can grab multiple words, separated by characters in `$IFS` (default: space, tab, newline)

```
while read -r d1 d2 d3 d4; do
    rectang -cs "$d1" "$d2" "$d3" "$d4"
done < file.csv
```

---

Given your modified data (fields separated with comma and spaces), I'd do this:

```
while IFS=",$IFS" read -r d1 d2 d3 d4; do # ...
```

to include the comma as a field separator.

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked fine. Kndly what is the meaning of $IFS?

Comment: That's the shell's "Internal Field Separator". See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting

Answer (score 0):

If the file is like that:

```
cat table.txt | while read i
do
    rectang -cs  $i
done
```

This will call:

```
rectang -cs 5  6  9  5
rectang -cs 2  8  1  1
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Glenn is of course mighty fine, but in this type of cases I would use `awk` to generate the command lines, and then pipe the results to a shell. As `awk` is part of POSIX, it arguably would be a valid solution.

```
awk -F'[, ]+' '{print "rectang -cs", $1, $2, $3, $4}' table.csv | sh
```

or, assigning the first field to the first field to trigger a recomputation of the field separator:

```
awk -F'[, ]+' '$1=$1{print "rectang -cs", $0}' table.csv | sh
```

Alternatively, with a similar pattern:

```
sed -e 's/^/rectang -cs /' -e 's/, */ /g' table.csv | sh
```

Of course, while experimenting, you can just look at the commands, and only if you are really sure, you pipe it to `sh`.